# OpenProject OmniAuth SAML Single-Sign On Integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, single-sign-on, saml, openproject

I am try to set up the SSO(Single Sign-On) integration with OpenProject using the [OpenProject OmniAuth SAML Single-Sign On](https://github.com/finnlabs/openproject-auth_saml) plugin. I have configured it with the relevant details. Generated the metadata and registered it with the IDP that is powered by Shibboleth. The plugin does show an additional login button on the openproject login form. Clicking it is properly redirecting to the IDP's login page. After giving the credentials, it is correctly redirecting to the AssertionConsumerService URL I have mentioned. It is of the form `https://example.com/openproject/auth/saml/callback`. But the page is showing a bad request error. Debugging the file `app/controllers/concerns/omniauth_login.rb` showed that, inside the `omniauth_login` function, the following lines of code is resulting in the 400 error.

```
auth_hash = request.env['omniauth.auth']

return render_400 unless auth_hash.valid?
```

The value of `auth_hash` looks to be empty. Could this be an issue due to attribute mapping or something else? I am coming from PHP bacnkground and have no experience in ruby on rails. So finding it difficult to debug the issue. I have tried googling a lot but couldn't find anything useful.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

replace the following code

```
uid { @name_id }
```

with the following code

```
  uid do
        if options.uid_attribute
          ret = find_attribute_by([options.uid_attribute])
          if ret.nil?
            raise OmniAuth::Strategies::SAML::ValidationError.new("SAML response missing '#{options.uid_attribute}' attribute")
          end
          ret
        else
          @name_id
        end
      end
```

inside the

> strategies/saml.rb

file. It is inside the  `def other_phase` function

For reference please have a look into the following github link
https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth-saml/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategies/saml.rb line number 90